# Limit characters per line in the multiline asp:textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, multiline

I am expecting a list from user separated by newline. Now I wish to limit user entering more than 50 character per line (after 50 characters user should not be able to type , new entry of 50 characters can be created upon pressing enter).

I am using multiline textbox in asp.net .

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Well, you could use a single line TextBox with the MaxLength set to 50 and capture when the user presses enter to add the TextBox value to JS array, display the values of the array on screen and then clear the TextBox ready for new entry...

Comment: thanks! Your idea gave me clue for a workaround. :)